δὲ in 1 Corinthians 11:3
1 Corinthians 11:3 (ESV),
3 But I want you to understand that the head of every man is Christ, the head of a wife is her husband, and the head of Christ is God.
The word that I've emboldened above translates the Greek particle δὲ.
There are multiple ways to understand the particle, and as such, it gets translated in multiple ways. Examples include "and", "but", "but rather", and "however".
See: https://biblehub.com/greek/1161.htm
Sometimes, the particle is given as a "mild adversative" (See link above). In the context of 1 Corinthians 11:3, what would a mild adversative indicate?
Prior to verse 3, Paul has urged the Corinthians to imitate him, as he imitates Christ, and has commended them for remembering him in everything and for maintaining the traditions just as he had delivered them, to them.
Immediately following comes the mild adversative particle δὲ.
Is Paul's use of δὲ suggestive of "But/However" as if to slightly contradict what he had just written in verses 1 and 2, that though he was generally happy with them in the manner just described, he nonetheless had a complaint against them to make, indicating that they were falling short in their imitation and remembering of him and their maintenance of the delivered traditions?
Is δὲ better understood as "But rather", suggesting the possibility that Paul is about to give the Corinthians a new way of imitating and remembering him, or a better tradition than the ones previously delivered?
Is δὲ better understood as "and", a conjunctive suggesting that the textual material which follows is a continuation of the material in verses 1 and 2, indicating that Paul is summarizing the imitation, remembrance, and traditions he expects of them with the material that follows?
Is δὲ better understood some other way?

I agree that δὲ (de) should be translated as "but" or "however".  The sense of 1 Cor 11:2 & 3 appears to be (Dottard's extreme paraphrase):

Thanks for remembering me in your prayers, BUT do not forget that the
head of every man is Christ ...

That is, great that you have done this BUT don't forget that.
Now, whether one calls this adversative or not is a matter of taste.  I think the best description is simply a grammatical contrast for effect.

The meaning is that he rewards them with the previous verse and places another lesson important. However or but. "But" I think is better.

δὲ is a conjunctive particle, standing for "and," "but," "or," "so," etc., in a continuing sentence, and in a weaker sense than και. Context determines the appropriate translation.
